# PostgreSQL how to group results so all rows must be true?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

In PostgreSQL, I have a query that can return 1 or more rows of boolean. How can I run a select query against this result set to get a single boolean that returns true if all of the rows are true? It returns false if one or more rows in this result set is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing boolean aggregation, for which Postgres offers built-in functions such as `bool_or()` and `bool_and()`:

```
select bool_and(mybool) as myresult
from (
  --- your query, that returns a boolean column called "mybool"
) t
```

Comment: how do I run this in PgAdmin? Where does "mybool" go? do you have an example?

Comment: I got it. mybool is the result of my query. it looks like it works! Yes!

Comment: @user840930: yes. You did not show your query so I can't really provide the full solution.

Comment: I understand. mybool goes at the end of the select and before the from clause.

Answer (score 0):

It might be faster to use `not exists`:

```
select not exists (select 1
                   from <your query>
                   where not mybool
                  )
```